# Convert point file to polyline but not joining every set of points in ArcGIS10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, line, geometry-conversion

I have a dataset that looks like :

```
   OBJECTID   Shape   KP     DESCRIPTION  EASTING  NORTHING
      1       Point   0.04    Span;Start   525112.2 6728715.4
      2       Point   0.0506  Span;End     525122.2 6728716.5
      3       Point   0.0667  Span;Start   525138.6 6728718.7
      4       Point   0.0506  Span;End     525142.7 6728719.2
```

Projection is UTM30-ED50 and there are 1462 points in the file.

What I want to do is **join** each pair of points **between** the Start and End span, then leave a gap between the End and the next Start point.

I have run Point to Line, easy, but this joins every point. Is there a way of specifying only the pairs of points I want to join? Or dissolving the parts of the line I don't want to keep after I have used, say, XTools, to split the line by points?

Dumb question, I realise, but I just can't work this out!

Comment: Are they ALWAYS (no exceptions) ordered with the start point first, followed by the end point second?  Never flipped?

Comment: Yes, Ryan. Never flipped.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to create another integer attribute and give a number the rows as follows 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6 (assuming your start and end point are alternate).  You can create a function in the field calculator to work this out from the row number.  Then create your lines as before but use this new attribute as the line ID.

Answer (score 0):

"XY to Line" would work, but instead of each row being a start/end point, it would be a line feature defined by the coordinates of the two points.

I see some Excel work in your future.